# How to delete an local queue after deleting q file

Tags: ibm-mq

MQ file system got 100% used in one of our queue managers and we found that our system.cluster.transmit queue is occupied the full space so I have deleted the q file.so file system issue got resolved.Now I was trying to delete the transmit local queue using delete qlocal command so I need to create the queue again as my queue got damaged but when I am trying to delete the queue I am getting MQ object is in use and I checked the handles to kill it but it says MQ object got damaged so please help me to how to delete the queue now.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running linear logging you can recreate the damaged object, but in this case that would fill the file system.  Instead, temporarily define a new QMgr and then get a copy of its file for the same queue and drop it into the directory where you deleted the file.

As a side note, you might also want to start a new question asking how to delete the messages in the XMitQ without blowing away the file.